# Change Django secret key within script

Tags: python, django, secret-key

I have a python script that requires changing the django `SECRET_KEY` multiple times throughout execution. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
from django.core import signing

# SECRET_KEY = "abc"
print signing.dumps("value")
# SECRET_KEY = "123"
print signing.dumps("value")
# SECRET_KEY = "test"
print signing.dumps("value")
```

The `signing.dumps` method requires a `SECRET_KEY` to be already setup though, it does not seem to have an argument to change it within the script.

How would I go about changing the `SECRET_KEY` multiple times within my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the [`dumps` method in `signing.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/signing.py#L96), you will see that it accepts a key as the signing key:

> If key is None, settings.SECRET_KEY is used instead.

```
def dumps(obj, key=None, salt='django.core.signing', serializer=JSONSerializer, compress=False):
    """
    Returns URL-safe, sha1 signed base64 compressed JSON string. If key is
    None, settings.SECRET_KEY is used instead.
    If compress is True (not the default) checks if compressing using zlib can
    save some space. Prepends a '.' to signify compression. This is included
    in the signature, to protect against zip bombs.
    Salt can be used to namespace the hash, so that a signed string is
    only valid for a given namespace. Leaving this at the default
    value or re-using a salt value across different parts of your
    application without good cause is a security risk.
    The serializer is expected to return a bytestring.
    """
```

So all you need to do is pass the different secret keys around everytime:

```
SECRET_KEY = "abc"
print signing.dumps("value", key=SECRET_KEY)
SECRET_KEY = "123"
print signing.dumps("value", key=SECRET_KEY)
```

That said, this looks like a bad idea to me since you are not signing with the default key. If you really need to sign texts, use the [`Signer class`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/signing.py#L149) to create, and instantiate objects with new `key` there and use it like `Signer(key="NEW KEY")`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You don't need to change your SECRET_KEY.  In fact, if you do, you won't be able to unsign something that you've signed!
2. The signing.dumps() function is for complex data types, such as dictionaries and tuples.

If you have a single value that you're trying to sign, you can do the following:

```
from django.core.signing import Signer
signer = Signer()
value = signer.sign('My string')
```

... and then after the form is posted you can verify the signature ...

```
try:
    original = signer.unsign(value)
except signing.BadSignature:
    print("Tampering detected!")
```

Comment: You can also set a key using: signer = Signer('my-other-secret')